# Is there a way to detect changes in a graph created with NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, pickle

I am a beginner Python programmer, and I would really appreciate your help with the following issue.

I have a first script that creates a graph and saves it as a Pickle file:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
#Some code lines to add nodes and edges...

nx.write_gpickle(G, "graph_file.gpickle")
```

Then, I have a second script where I want to read the Pickle file and detect any changes in the graph nodes attributes, in case the first script was rerun with different values for the nodes attributes:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_gpickle("graph_file.gpickle")

#I need to implement something like this:
for node in G.nodes():
    if node["attribute"] changed from previous value:
        print(f"The attribute of the node {node} changed from {previous value of node["attribute"]} to {new value of node["attribute"]}")
```

Comment: Where are the values from the previous run?

Comment: @ThomasSablik They are stored in the "graph_file.gpickle" file, which is replaced in each run.

Comment: And where are the new values?

Comment: There is only one file ("graph_file.gpickle"). Each time the first script is rerun with new input parameters, the output graph is saved with the same file name, thus replacing the previous one.

Comment: Do you understand it right? You want to run a script that reads a file. The script and the Python process stop. You change the file and run the script. Now you want to see differences between both runs?

Comment: I apologise if what I said was confusing, I am a complete beginner at programming so please bear with me :)

To answer your question, yes I would like a way to capture the difference in nodes attributes (e.g., save the previous nodes somewhere before the file gets replaced if that's possible?)

Comment: Of course my question was _"Do I understand it right?"_ You have to store both graphs.

Comment: Does it mean that each time I run the first script, the graph file should be saved under a new name?
If so, how can I refer to the last two files in my second script?

Comment: You have to specify _"last two files"_? You could read timestamp or your could add an unique number to each file.

Comment: Is there any module or package that would allow me to identify instances of difference, or should I just use a for loop to compare every single node from the 2 graphs?
Also, I found in my search something called the Observer pattern. Would that be appropriate in my case?